# IIS 6 Redirects and passing parameters

Tags: iis, iis-6, redirect

I'm trying to configure our IIS server so that when an old page is requested such as 
http://mycompany.com/details.asp?item_id=1111
it should redirect to
http://mycompany.com/items/1111

I'm not sure which is the best way to do this? 
1. In the web.config file of the project... but I'm not sure this caters for variables
2. MetaBase... we're trying this at the moment using VBScript, but having problems since we're very new to it
3. Other?

Any help would be great.

Thanks
Jacques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet in IIS6 is [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/).  It's meant for this exact situation.  When you move to IIS7, there's built in support with URL Rewrite.

Edit:
Since this is IIS6, web.config won't be able to redirect a .asp page (non-managed code) unless you map .asp to aspnet_isapi.dll instead of asp.dll (but then it won't process the pages the same).  So IIS6 can't cleanly natively do this by itself.

What you can do is in your details.asp page watch for item_id=something and do a Response.redirect.

Or you can do this in global.asa Application_BeginRequest if you want it more generic and for multiple pages.

Comment: We're not able to upload a 3rd party rewrite module for this. We'd have to rely on the Metabase, or similar scenario where the functionality already exists.

Comment: I'll reply to this by editing my original post ...